# AJAX add to cart code gives no error but not running with PHP MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying hard to find the problem, here is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#addItem", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest(".form-submit");
        var id = form.find(".pid").val();
        var name = form.find(".pname").val();
        var price = form.find(".pprice").val();
        var image = form.find(".pimage").val();
        var code = form.find(".pcode").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {pid:id, pname:name, pprice:price, pimage:image, pcode:code},
            success:function(response){
            
                $(".alert-message").html(response);
                
                window.scrollTo(20,2);
                load_cart_item_number();
            }
        });
    });

    load_cart_item_number();

    function load_cart_item_number() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {cartItem: "cart_item"},
            success:function(response){
                $("#cart-item").html(response);
            
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and HTML form :

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?php echo $row['product_id'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $row['product_name'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?php echo $row['product_price'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="<?php echo $row['product_image'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?php echo $row['product_code'] ?>">
    <button id="addItem" class="btn add-to-cart">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

the only problem is `add to cart` button is not working and there is no error in console showing.

Comment: Try some debugging, like `console.log(response);`, if you are stuck with something debugging is the best choice, try debugging from top to bottom, from button click, accessing form elements, ajax call, to response, you can catch and fix it.

Comment: Also check if the HTTP call is made, from the devtools network tab

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am not good with js, just recently tried ajax for the first time

Comment: Well you need to learn to debug your AJAX at the same time as you learn to code it. That's why the comments above are giving you help about how to debug it!

Comment: Also we can't see your action.php so if the error is on the server side we definitely cannot help you with that